# Run a .py with txt test case entry and redirect output to another .txt

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a command from java, to run a Python file (which one I've created also in my code) with a test case file as entry and redirect It's output to another .txt file. The command looks like:
`python < testCase1.txt > output.txt file.py`
And I've tried also with absolute path
`python < /home/mateus/IdeaProjects/coyote/testCase1.txt > /home/mateus/IdeaProjects/coyote/output.txt /home/mateus/IdeaProjects/coyote/file.py`

The problem I'm facing is: after running this command using ProcessBuilder the output of the python code Isn't redirected to the output.txt. If I run from Unix terminal properly, It does works very well.

I've already tried with Runtime.Exec() and ProcessBuilder. I tried use process.getInputStream() but as the command don't return information on terminal, it doesn't work.

```
public boolean runSourceCode() throws IOException {

    // creating py file
    Files.write( Paths.get(this.nameFile) , this.sourceCode.getBytes());

    // Creating the processbuilder
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder("python", String.format("< %s > %s %s", "./testCase1.txt", "./output.txt", String.format("./"+this.nameFile)) ).start();
}
```

EDIT 1
So I've fixed myself, What I needed to do is:

```
// running python
            ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("python3" , namePyFile);
            p.redirectInput(new File( TestFiles.get(i) ) );
            p.redirectOutput(new File(saidaFileName));
            p.start().waitFor();
```

It's also needed to use ```throws InterruptedException`` after method's signature becaseu we're using waitFor() method which is going to wait to the proccess run.

Comment: You may wish to grab the output stream and error stream to see if they *are* putting out any key information, the error stream in particular.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote: *If I run from Unix terminal, it works* `ProcessBuilder` is not a UNIX terminal. That's why it has method [redirectOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.io.File-), for example. An ancient article, but still relevant, in my opinion: [When Runtime.exec() won't](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html). You can basically replace class `Runtime` with class `ProcessBuilder`. When the article was written, class `ProcessBuilder` did not exist.